# barycentric coordinate clamping on 3d triangle

Tags: c++, math, geometry

I am going to calculate the shortest distance from a point to a triangle(3d). I have projected the point to the plane of the triangle and than taken the barycentric coordinates of the projection of the point. But i could not find a way to clamp the coordinates to always be inside the triangle.

when searching I've only found the 0 <= [u,v,w] and u+v+w = 1. but how would this be solved?

Comment: If the projection on the plane is not in the triangle, you can forget it and look at the distance to the segments.

Comment: oh, dident think of that. still if its possible to clamp, it would probably be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't clamp a point to a triangle that way if you want to find the shortest distance from a point to a triangle. Distance is in Cartesian space, whereas barycentric coordinates are not.

In order to determine the distance of a point to a triangle that is outside the triangle, you need to determine which feature of the triangle the point is closest to (line segment, or corner), then the distance to that feature. Clamping barycentric coordinates in any way that does not take into account the transformation back to Cartesian space will simply not work.

Comment: Are you sure? The method i described gave me a pretty good result for my purpose (voxelicing mesh). Ofcourse i dont calculate the distance in barycentric space, but convert the clamped point back to world space again. Might do some tests later to ceck accuracy.

Comment: @lasvig, clamping in barycentric space gets you the distance to a point on the triangle. That point on the triangle is not necessarily the closest point on the triangle to the query point.

Answer (score 10):

I realise this is an old question, but it hasn't really been answered yet, and it's currently the first hit on Google for "clamp barycentric coordinates".

In the following, `p0`, `p1`, `p2` are the vertices of the triangle and `u`, `v`, `w` are the barycentric coordinates of the point `p = p0*u + p1*v + p2*w`.  I'm assuming that `u+v+w = 1`.

As MSN points out, the nearest point on the triangle depends on the triangle, so any operation on just `u`, `v`, `w` can't work.

If all of `u`, `v`, `w` are positive, then the point is in the triangle and there is nothing to do.

If any of them are negative, then the point is on the wrong side of the corresponding edge.  We need to move the point onto that edge.  Points on the edge of a triangle have zero for the corresponding barycentric coordinate.  The other two are simply how far the point is from one end to the other.

```
if ( u < 0)
{
    float t = Dot(p-p1,p2-p1)/Dot(p2-p1,p2-p1);
    t = Clamp01( t );
    return Vector3( 0.0f, 1.0f-t, t );
}
else if ( v < 0 )
{
    float t = Dot(p-p2,p0-p2)/Dot(p0-p2,p0-p2);
    t = Clamp01( t );
    return Vector3( t, 0.0f, 1.0f-t );
}
else if ( w < 0 )
{
    float t = Dot(p-p0,p1-p0)/Dot(p1-p0,p1-p0);
    t = Clamp01( t );
    return Vector3( 1.0f-t, t, 0.0f );
}
else
{
    return Vector3( u, v, w );
}
```

`Clamp01()` returns `t` if it is between `0` and `1`, `0` if it is negative, or `1` if it is greater than `1`. `Dot( a, b )` is the dot product of two vectors `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Try clamping `u` and `v` to `0..1` and then set `w = 1 - u - v` to keep the normalization constraint.

Comment: tried it and it dident seem to work but my code might be wrong, trying to fix to test again.

Answer (score 0):

`u`, `v` and `w` need to be clamped between `0..1`. That's it.

So for example

```
[u,v,w] = [-0.17, 0.64, 1.85]
```

on the triangle would be

```
[u,v,w] = [0, 0.64, 1]
```

Comment: And what do you do with those "clamped" u, v and w? What do they mean?

Comment: would that actually clamp it to the closest point to the original coords? i tried this before, but it might be some error in my test code. will try some more.

Comment: It's legal to have barycentric coords where u + v + w != 1?

Comment: Yes. Barycentric coordinates are homogeneous. This means that `[u,v,w]` and `[2u,2v,2w]` point to the same location. So you can always divide by a scalar to make `u+v+w=1` but you don't have to. To extract the `(x,y)` coordinates in the end you would need to do the division, but mathematically speaking any value is valid.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone want to know, I solved it by first 
clamping `u` and `v` and `w = 1 - u - v` than 
clamping `u` and `w` and `v = 1 - u - w` than
clamping `v` and `w` and `u = 1 - v - w`

the other 2 suggested solutions gave me weird outputs and dident seem  to clamp correctly.

there is probably better/faster ways of doing it but for now this work.