# How to set boundaries for a draggable object?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, geometry

I want the black button not to move out of the triangle, (see Flickr link)
and if it goes over the edge of the triangle, that the button is returned back into the triangle.

How do I do that?

http://www.flickr.com/photos/92202376@N08/8590549046/in/photostream

```
#import "DraggableViewController.h"

@interface DraggableViewController ()

@end

@implementation DraggableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create a new button
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Scale9Image.png"]
                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // add drag listener
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

    // center and size
    button.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width - 100)/1.6,
                              (self.view.bounds.size.height - 50)/1.9,
                              40, 40);
    button.frame.origin.y;

    [self.view addSubview:button];

}

- (void)wasDragged:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // get the touch
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:button] anyObject];

    // get delta
    CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:button];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:button];
    CGFloat delta_x = location.x - previousLocation.x;
    CGFloat delta_y = location.y - previousLocation.y;

    // move button
    button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x + delta_x,
                                button.center.y + delta_y);
}
@end
```

Comment: When you're tracking the drag, don't move the black button outside the triangle. (I could give you a more specific answer if you have a more specific question.)

Comment: @Caleb how should i ask ?? english is not my first language... and i find it quitte difficult how to explain... sorry... but what i mean is : the black button on the photo must not come out of the triangle... so the button must stay in that certain "area" u know ?

Comment: You should tell us how you're currently managing to drag the button. Are you tracking touches yourself? Using a gesture recognizer? Doing something else? Maybe show the code that does the drag tracking. In any case, you obviously have some code somewhere that moves the button, right? Fundamentally, you need to modify that code so that it doesn't move the button beyond whatever boundary you decide on. As things stand, we can't discuss that code because only one of us can see it.

Comment: how should i tell the button to not move over the boundary ? @Caleb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that line where you move the button in `-wasDragged`?

```
button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x + delta_x,
                            button.center.y + delta_y);
```

You can prevent the button from leaving the triangle by testing the new point to make sure that it's inside the triangle before you move the button. Better, you can simply compute the point inside the triangle that's closest to the new point and use that, so the button will still move as the touch moves outside the triangle, but it will be constrained to the triangle:

```
CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(button.center.x + delta_x,
                                button.center.y + delta_y);
button.center = [self buttonPositionNearestToPoint:newPoint];
```

Of course, you'll need to implement the `-buttonPositionNearestToPoint:` method. You'll need a little computational geometry to do that. Check out [Point in triangle test](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/) for a gentle introduction. [barycentric coordinate clamping on 3d triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14467296/643383) may also prove helpful even though it's 3D instead of 2D.